# XMPP Client Account Register

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xmpp, xmppframework

I am creating a client chat application using C# with WPF. I have download Xmpp application written in C#. Its function works well. I want to create new Account using this library but i don't know how to write or where to find it.

Could anybody help me...

Comment: Hello you can try with this article, he is interessant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx

Comment: to be able to help we need to know which software you have downloaded and which XMPP library it is using.

Comment: I have downloaded XMPP library from [http://code.google.com/p/xmppapplication/](http://code.google.com/p/xmppapplication/)

Answer (score 1):

the client you downloaded is based on jabber-net. Here in the FAQs is the answer to your question:
http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/FAQ_Register